# BLE file transfer: read of single GATT characteristic as bottleneck

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

I need to read files (size up to 100 KB) from an **embedded device** that supports **only Bluetooth Low Energy** (BLE). The reader is an **Android device** (minSDK 33).

A single file is “served” in chunks of data in a GATT characteristic. Another characteristic contains the file size (a file size > 0 indicates that there’s a file to read). To request the next chunk, the app writes yet another characteristic.

Now I encounter a bottleneck: The time between a single read (using android BluetoothGatt.readCharacteristic) and read callback (onCharacteristicRead) is always > 80 milliseconds.

This limits the maximum bandwidth because at most I can do 12.5 reads per second. Even if I read 509 bytes each time I’m stuck at 6.300 bytes/s. This is not considering the time of the overhead the write of the chunk counter characteristic entails.

In practice, I probably have to use a chunk size of 128 bytes. This limits the bandwidth to 1.600 byte/s.

*Is there any other way to do this single read faster? Or is this just as fast as it gets?*

I’ve googled and read similar questions on Stack Overflow, but I have not found any information about a realistic maximum speed for a scenario like mine.

Thank you!

Comment: So for each chunk you have to perform a write and a read? Sounds to me that also the API is not optimized for speed. When reading large data I would use notification/indication as response to the write command for retrieving the data. That would eliminate the read operation.

Comment: Thanks for your comment and suggestion @Robert! This is the way I tried, but not a satisfactory performance improvement.

Answer (score 0):

You have basically two solutions to improve the throughput:

1. Use GATT notifications. Make sure you have a large MTU (such as 517). Send notifications of 495 bytes, assuming the Link Layer supports 251 byte large PDUs.
2. Use L2CAP Connection oriented channels.

Theoretically (i.e. according to the spec), the second approach is more stable since it correctly deals with flow control and interleaving with other communication data, while notifications are allowed to be dropped by the receiver if it can't keep up with the flow.

In practice, GATT notifications work good too and is usually much simpler to use. Android, as far as I know, never drops incoming notifications.

The reason it's much slower using Read transactions is that you can only have one pending Read at a time and it's usually not possible to handle more than one Read Request in a connection event; typically two connection intervals can handle only one Read transaction. With the one-way communication methods, there is no application level ack involved or similar, so the LE packet queue can be filled, allowing the Link Layer to send many packets in every connection event.